# Query Custom Post Type by Taxonomy Meta Value

Tags: taxonomy, advanced-taxonomy-queries, term-meta

I need to filter my custom post type "**events**" by Taxonomy Meta Field "**city**". But I can't make it work and need some help?

This is what I already have. But no results...

```
function aa_pre_get_posts($query)   {
    if (is_admin() || $query->get('post_type') != 'my-events') return;

    if(isset($_GET['city']) and trim($_GET['city']))
    {
        $query->set(
            'tax_query',
            array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'my_location',
                    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                        'meta_query' => [[
                        'key' => 'city',
                        'value' => sanitize_text_field($_GET['city']),
                        'compare' => 'LIKE'
                    ]], 
                )               
            )
        );
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'aa_pre_get_posts');
```

So, what's wrong?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't possible via `WP_Query`, but more importantly, this would be stupendously expensive. Taxonomy queries are expensive. Post meta queries are super super expensive. Like queries are also expensive.

Finding all posts that have a term that has a meta that is like X, is an astoundingly expensive/slow query. Writing this out as a custom SQL query is the only option, and I would be surprised if the query finished in under 10 seconds. It could easily bring down a database server if your site gets a moderate or higher level of concurrent traffic.

**Would it not be orders of magnitude faster and simpler to have a city taxonomy?** If you need to filter or search for posts by something, use taxonomy terms. Meta is not for searching